# I am trying to make the table displayed (using Datatables) downloadable in csv format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, csv, datatables

I have been assigned with a task to display a table (columns should be searchable and sortable.) Since I have essentially no experience with javascript or Jquery, I decided to use one of the plugins that are available and used DataTables. Here is the link for that file.

```
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Now, I want to be able to offer an option, to download the able displayed in .csv format. I need to make sure that they **can only download the results they searched for and not the entire table.**

I have been using the following code to implement the search/sorting table.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#table_id thead th").each (function(){
                var title = $("#table_id thead th").eq( $(this).index()).text();
                $(this).html (' <input type = "text" placeholder = "Search '+title+'"/> ');
            });

            var table = $('#table_id').DataTable();

            table.columns().every(function(){
                var that = this;

                $( 'input', this.header() ).on ( 'keyup change', function(){
                    that
                        .search( this.val() )
                        .draw();
                } );
            });

        });

    </script>
```

If anyone can tel me how to implement that or point me towards some other plugin which has the needed option, It'd be really helpful.

Ps: I am just starting to learn javascript now, so I will be able to code this in the future from scratch I hope.

Comment: If you're not averse to using a wee bit of flash in your page then TableTools (https://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/) offers what you need - and so much more! It really is a cracking tool! Alternatively you need to introduce a button/link into the page which calls a server-side script to generate the data in the appropriate format. That's not trivially easy though eminently doable. You'll be able to get the relevant paging data from the table using the API but again, not trivial - whereas TableTools can do it all for you.

Comment: I tried to use that extension couple of days back. However, It did not work as intended, The file that I downloaded used to contain some of the source code in it, So I refrained from using it. (I was close to the deadline for the first part.) I will try to use it again and let you know. Thanks for taking your tip.

Answer (score 0):

I have the next code to generate a .csv  from a Datatable for download, getting the records filtered and ordered.

```
function exportcsv(){
var tabledata = $('selectorJquery').DataTable();
var table = tabledata._('tr', {"filter": "applied"});
var columns = tabledata.dataTableSettings[0].aoColumns;
var tableString = "";

//Get the title headers and add to the first line of .csv
$.each(columns, function(i,v) { 
    tableString += v.sTitle+";";
    });
//Add line break and get the length of rows and the length of cols
tableString += "\r\n";
var rowLength = table.length;
var colLength = table[0].length;
//Iterate all rows and cols
for (var j = 0; j < rowLength; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < colLength; k++) {
        tableString += (k==colLength)  ?  table[j][k] : table[j][k]+";";
    }
    tableString += "\r\n";
}
  //Put the headers of file, application/csv and charset UTF-8 with BOM and the string with data rows
   csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,\uFEFF' + encodeURIComponent(tableString);
    var d = new Date();
     //Here I put in href attribute of a <a> HTML element and the .csv file starts to download automatically with name=yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss.csv
     $('selectorJquery').attr({
         'href': csvData,
         'target': '_blank',
         'download': d.getFullYear()+"-"+("0" + d.getMonth()).slice (-2)+"-"+("0" + d.getDate()).slice (-2)+"_"+("0" + d.getHours()).slice (-2)+"-"+("0" + d.getMinutes()).slice (-2)+"-"+("0" + d.getSeconds()).slice (-2)+'.csv'
     });
 }

}
```

I hope this function can help you to fix your problem.